# Angular JS - Problem deleting row from table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

#AngularJS
I have a table. When I click the DELETE button on any row, the following code always deletes the first one. Where am I wrong? I'll post part of the code

```
            <tr id="riga" ng-repeat='x in cars'>
                <td class="dimensione">{{x.id}}</td>
                <td class="dimensione">{{x.targaauto}}</td>
                <td class="dimensione">{{x.datiintestatario}}</td>
                <td class="dimensione">{{x.marca}}</td>
                
                
                <td><button type="button" class='btn btn-danger btn' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#finestra">                 elimina</button></td>
            </tr>
                <div class="modal fade " id="finestra">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Attenzione</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <h5 class="modal-body">Sei sicuro di voler eliminare questo record?</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='rimuovi($index)' data-bs-                           dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">ANNULLA</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </table>
        </tbody>
      <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Function RIMUOVI

```
$scope.rimuovi=function($index){
    $scope.cars.splice($index, 1)
}
```

Comment: $index in known only inside the ng-repeat block. Your window is outside that block, so the $index passed to rimuovi  function in always incorect.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-danger btn' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#finestra">                 elimina</button>
```

button, you need to add

```
ng-click="verifyDelete($index)"
```

which you will save in your directive/controller. That way, when you ask "Are you sure" from the modal, you have the correct row.

Update  `ng-click='rimuovi($index)'` to  `ng-click='rimuovi()'` and use the value saved from verifyDelete

Comment: Resolved. thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access the $index variable outside the ng-repeat block. To fix this you should store it to a variable in your controller when you click delete and then show the modal.

Or you can pass the object and then make a filter on the array, but the tow options require you to store the value to a variable.